# transpose multiple different columns to rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

please have a look at the lists attached. how to transpose from A to B ?

[image: A]

[image: B]

Comment: What have you tried? Don't just post images!!! Google INDEX, MATCH and FILTER functions. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to Google a bit.
If you have the latest version of Excel, use the `UNIQUE`, `FILTER` and `TRANSPOSE` functions. Adapt the following to suit you data.

- To obtain the unique equipment list

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A10)
```

- Filter and transpose them base on the equipment criteria

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$1:$B$10,$A$1:$A$10=E6))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, can this be done with google sheets ?

Comment: @AhmedYahya I don't know as I don't use google sheets.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked with google sheet. really appreciate your support